# Bootstrap button default type

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, types, default

Do Bootstrap buttons default to a specific type if a type is not assigned? I have seen some unusual behaviour in a form that I have:

```
<form action="blah blah" method="POST" id="blah" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-wide">
            <!-- Button 1 -->
            <button class="close cancel-btn" >&times;</button>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="password" class="text long" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <ul class="h-list">
                        <!-- Button 2 Submit -->
                        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-acknowledge main-action">
                            <i class="icon-btn icon-btn-check"></i> <span class="text">Confirm</span>
                        </button>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Button 3 -->
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn-cancel close cancel-btn"">Cancel
                        </button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This form has three buttons, one with type of submit and another with a type of button. The other 'X' or close button does not have a type specified.

I noticed then when I hit enter on my keyboard, with the modal open, that the modal was closed. The only way I could submit the form was to click on the submit button. The Javascript I have triggers on a submit action. So, I had anticipated the my form would be submitted but instead the form is closed leading me to believe that Bootstrap buttons default to have a type of submit. Is this correct and is there any documentation out there on this? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I successfully added a type of button to the first button and this seems to have validated my thinking but I would like some clarification on this in the form of documentation or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type = "button"` attribute to first button element.

If it doesn't work maybe you can try adding hotkey's.

[Bootstrap Dialog manuplation](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)

Comment: Sorry, this is what I already did, I will edit my question. However, the question I asked is "Do Bootstrap buttons default to a specific type if a type is not assigned?" and I was looking for documentation to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, bootstrap does not have default button property. You have to modify it for this. (as bootstrap's priority is to design your page) This solved your problem because HTML Form element assign Enter hotkey to the first button which is defined as type = submit. Maybe you should search for a document in HTML sources.